# How to use MediaStore API in flutter

Tags: flutter-dependencies

I make a Gallery application application in flutter to take take permission so i use  and import permission handler but Play store reject my application due to the same. And say use MediaStore API How to use MediaStore API in flutter .

how To use MediaStore API in flutter to system permission.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.